# Why Won't This Show/Hide Toggle Function Work in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, toggle, display

I have been attempting to troubleshoot a show/hide toggle script that just doesn't seem to run properly on Safari... Though, it works fine on Chrome and Firefox, for some reason, it does not display the toggle effect at all in Safari. Any advice as to why this would occur?

Here is a snippet which demonstrates the function I am working with:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var div2 = $('#pgnav');
  var div1 = $('#container2');
  $window.on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var viewport_height = $window.height();
    var scrollTop_bottom = scrollTop + viewport_height;
    var window_top_to_div2 = ($window.height() - div2.height()) / 2;
    var div1_top = div1.offset().top;
    var div1_height = div1.height();
    var div1_bottom = div1_top + div1_height;
    div2.toggleClass('show', scrollTop >= (div1_top - window_top_to_div2) && (scrollTop + window.innerHeight) <= (div1_bottom + window_top_to_div2));
  });
});
```

```css
#pgnav {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms, visibility 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms, visibility 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms, visibility 500ms;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#pgnav.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

#pgnav .wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#pgnav .navbtns,
#pgnav-min .navbtns {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

#pgnav .navbtns svg,
#pgnav-min .navbtns svg {
  fill: blue;
  opacity: .8;
  overflow: visible;
  will-change: opacity;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#pgnav .navbtns svg:hover,
#pgnav-min .navbtns svg:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#pgnav .prev {
  right: 0;
  margin-right: -25px;
}

#pgnav .next {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
}

#container1,
#container3 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#container2 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pgnav">
  <div class="wrap">
    <a href="#" class="navbtns prev" title="Go to Next Page">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50"><path d="M25,50A25,25,0,1,0,0,25,25,25,0,0,0,25,50ZM25,2A23,23,0,1,1,2,25,23,23,0,0,1,25,2Zm-3,9V39L32,25Z" style="fill-rule:evenodd"/></svg>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="navbtns next" title="Go to Previous Page">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50"><path d="M25,50A25,25,0,1,1,50,25,25,25,0,0,1,25,50ZM25,2A23,23,0,1,0,48,25,23,23,0,0,0,25,2Zm3,9V39L18,25Z" style="fill-rule:evenodd"/></svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container1">
  Scroll down to <b>#container2</b>
</div>
<div id="container2">
  This is <b>#container2</b>
</div>
<div id="container3">
  Scroll up to <b>#container2</b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51005505/9214076. There was a complication with `document.documentElement.scrollTop`. By replacing it with `$(window).scrollTop()`, the script now runs smoothly cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a newer version of JQuery? I don't have safari downloaded, but I put jquery 3.3.1 in the code snippet and it works on Firefox.
Let me know if this works!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var div2 = $('#pgnav');
  var div1 = $('#container2');
  $window.on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var viewport_height = $window.height();
    var scrollTop_bottom = scrollTop + viewport_height;
    var window_top_to_div2 = ($window.height() - div2.height()) / 2;
    var div1_top = div1.offset().top;
    var div1_height = div1.height();
    var div1_bottom = div1_top + div1_height;
    div2.toggleClass('show', scrollTop >= (div1_top - window_top_to_div2) && (scrollTop + window.innerHeight) <= (div1_bottom + window_top_to_div2));
  });
});
```

```css
#pgnav {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms, visibility 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms, visibility 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms, visibility 500ms;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#pgnav.show {
  display: inline;
  opacity: 1;
}

#pgnav .wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#pgnav .navbtns,
#pgnav-min .navbtns {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

#pgnav .navbtns svg,
#pgnav-min .navbtns svg {
  fill: blue;
  opacity: .8;
  overflow: visible;
  will-change: opacity;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#pgnav .navbtns svg:hover,
#pgnav-min .navbtns svg:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#pgnav .prev {
  right: 0;
  margin-right: -25px;
}

#pgnav .next {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
}

#container1,
#container3 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#container2 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pgnav">
  <div class="wrap">
    <a href="#" class="navbtns prev" title="Go to Next Page">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50"><path d="M25,50A25,25,0,1,0,0,25,25,25,0,0,0,25,50ZM25,2A23,23,0,1,1,2,25,23,23,0,0,1,25,2Zm-3,9V39L32,25Z" style="fill-rule:evenodd"/></svg>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="navbtns next" title="Go to Previous Page">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50"><path d="M25,50A25,25,0,1,1,50,25,25,25,0,0,1,25,50ZM25,2A23,23,0,1,0,48,25,23,23,0,0,0,25,2Zm3,9V39L18,25Z" style="fill-rule:evenodd"/></svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container1">
  Scroll down to <b>#container2</b>
</div>
<div id="container2">
  This is <b>#container2</b>
</div>
<div id="container3">
  Scroll up to <b>#container2</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but using version 3.3.1 didn't make a difference for me. The function still fails...

Comment: Here try changing visibility property to being display: none; for hidden and display: inline; for showing. I have edited my answer to show that in the code.

Comment: Thanks again, but that didn't do the trick... It also removed the fading visibility effect.